# EF Core, one-to-many relationship - how to insert records in both tables with a single view?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, scaffolding

I have two models set up as follows:

```cs
public class NewCourseCategoryForm
{
    public int NewCourseCategoryFormID { get; set; }            
    
    public virtual ICollection<ProposedCourse> ProposedCourse { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```cs
public class ProposedCourse
{
    public int ProposedCourseID { get; set; }           
    public string ProposedCourseName { get; set; }
    public string ProposedCourseDescription { get; set; }
    
    public NewCourseCategoryForm  { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbContext class definition, I have the following code which defines the relationships between the two aforementioned tables:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<NewCourseCategoryForm>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => NewCourseCategoryFormID                  
    entity.Property(e => e.NewCourseCategoryFormID).HasColumnName("NewCourseCategoryFormID");

    entity.HasMany(d => d.ProposedCourse)
          .WithOne(p => p.NewCourseCategoryForm);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProposedCourse>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.ProposedCourseID);    
        entity.Property(e => e.ProposedCourseName).HasColumnName("ProposedCourseName");
        entity.Property(e => e.ProposedCourseDescription).HasColumnName("ProposedCourseDescription");                   
    });
```

I want to create the CRUD pages for the `NewCourseCategoryForm` page. On the "Create" page, instead of seeing `ProposedCourseID`, I want to see the textboxes related to the `ProposedCourse` model for `ProposedCourseName` and `ProposedCourseDescription`. Whenever the user creates a new `NewCourseCategoryForm`, I want for records to be entered on to both tables like this:

```
+----------------------------+------------------+
| NewCourseCategoryFormID    | ProposedCourseID |
+----------------------------+------------------+
| 1                          | 123              |
+----------------------------+------------------+

+------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+
| ProposedCourseID | ProposedCourseName | ProposedCourseDescription |
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+
| 123              | Algebra 101        | Beginner algebra          |
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+
```

I'm feel certain that Entity Framework can handle something like this, but I have no idea where to begin looking. How can I make this happen? I even need the user to be able to enter a dynamic number of "Proposed Courses". So how can I accomplish that?

Comment: `public virtual ProposedCourse { get; set; }` what is the new syntax?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what "public virtual ..." accomplishes there - that is a remnant of code that was generated whenever I first used my database to create the skeleton of my application. Now I am using a code-first approach.

Comment: Well first of all you need to properly define a relationship.
public virtual ProposedCourse { get; set; }  This won't do anything...

Comment: I found documentation that described setting up one-to-many relationships here:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration

I'm going to update the code in my question

Comment: I'm leaving a note for myself here to look in to "View Models" next week.

Comment: This has nothing to do with EF. How you represent/edit data is responsibility of the presentation layer. While EF is just data persistence layer. And of course it can add multiple things in a single unit of work as soon as you pass the necessary data and write the necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

CourseViewModels.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class NewCourseCategoryForm
    {
        public int NewCourseCategoryFormID { get; set; }            
        
        public virtual ICollection<ProposedCourse> ProposedCourses { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProposedCourse
    {
        public int ProposedCourseID { get; set; }           
        public string ProposedCourseName { get; set; }
        public string ProposedCourseDescription { get; set; }
        
        public NewCourseCategoryForm Form { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CoursesController.cs:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class CoursesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CoursesController> _logger;

        public CoursesController(ILogger<CoursesController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(NewCourseCategoryForm form)
        {
            var newForm = new NewCourseCategoryForm
            {
                ProposedCourses = form.ProposedCourses.Select(s => new ProposedCourse
                {
                    ProposedCourseName = s.ProposedCourseName,
                    ProposedCourseDescription = s.ProposedCourseDescription
                }).ToList()
            };

            // _context.NewCourseCategoryForms.Add(newForm);
            // _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
    }
}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@model NewCourseCategoryForm
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<form method="post">
    <div id="courses" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProposedCourses[0].ProposedCourseName" placeholder="Name...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProposedCourses[0].ProposedCourseDescription" placeholder="Description...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="create()">New...</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Create</button>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 1;

        const create = () => {
            $("#courses").append(`
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Course name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProposedCourses[` + counter + `].ProposedCourseName" placeholder="Name...">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Course description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProposedCourses[` + counter + `].ProposedCourseDescription" placeholder="Description...">
                    </div>
                </div>
            `);

            counter++;
        }
    </script>
}
```

[image: Courses page]

[image: POSTed dataset]

Comment: At first I was confused, because nothing was saving to the database. Then I noticed the commented: "// _context.NewCourseCategoryForms.Add(newForm);
            // _context.SaveChanges();" and realized, of course, you have not created this database.

This does exactly what I need for it to do. Thank you so much. I will mark your answer as the correct one as soon as the bounty allows me to!

Comment: I have come back to this and discovered something interesting. I'm using EF Core 3.1. I don't have to modify the scaffolded controller at all - as long as I have the relationship between different classes mapped correctly, all I have to do is add the appropriate fields in the Views (with the correct "name" attribute matching the names of the individual fields) and the data insertion works properly.